# make onclick inside map reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hi guys i try to make onclick inside map looping , so the onclick inside the div , but i got error , infinite looping

here the code

```
{arrayqueue.map((item, index) => {
                  return (
                    <div className="row-queue" key={index} onClick={setMyvideo(item.videoname)}>
                      <div className="column1-queue">{index + 1}</div>
                      <div className="column2-queue">{item.title}</div>
                      <div className="column3-queue">{item.singer}</div>
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
```

can someone help me why this is error ?

Comment: can you share you setMyvideo function and also the error msg

Comment: You need to pass a function which calls `setMyVideo`, not a function call directly. So  it should be `onClick={() => setMyvideo(item.videoname)}`

Comment: @Jayce444 its fine if setMyvideo is a HOF which returns a function

Comment: @Jerryc yes that's true, I just assumed it wasn't since this seemed like a beginner asking, and they tend not to use HOFs very much. But yes Riky, you can add your `setMyVideo` definition if this doesn't fix it  to help clarify things. And include the specifics of your error message, it's exact text, where in the code it's happening, etc.

Answer (score 1):

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

```js
const [myvideo, setMyvideo] = useState(...)

...

{arrayqueue.map((item, index) => {
  return (
    <div className="row-queue" key={index} onClick={() => setMyvideo(item.videoname)}>
      <div className="column1-queue">{index + 1}</div>
      <div className="column2-queue">{item.title}</div>
      <div className="column3-queue">{item.singer}</div>
    </div>
  );
})}
```